# Assign db query value to t-sql variable in dynamic query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this requirement to be implemented in a stored procedure. Dynamically query the database to get the count of a table, store it in a t-sql variable and then take some decisions based on that.

This is the stored procedure that i am working on . This is throwing some errors as i don't think there is a simple way of assigning the result of a tsql dynamic query to a variable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @cnt int
 SET @sql = 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM myTable'
 SET @cnt = EXEC(@sql)
 IF (@cnt > 0)
     PRINT 'A'
 ELSE
     PRINT 'B'
END
GO
```

Could someone tell me if there is a simpler way of achieving this using T-SQL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

alternative:

```
declare @tablename varchar(512) = 'sometable'
declare @sql nvarchar(512) = 'set @count = (select count(*) from ' + @tablename + ')'
declare @count int

execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@count int output', @count=@count output

select case when @count > 0 then 'A' else 'B' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SET @sql = 'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(1) FROM myTable'
 EXEC(@sql)
```